# How did they do it? Realtime http://trendsmap.com/

Tags: php, jquery, web-services

I wanna know how did they do this site.
How did they do it? Realtime http://trendsmap.com/

Comment: Funny, I was just thinking something like this would be cool twenty minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha: http://trendsmap.com/about-faq :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Flex?

OK, you want use jQuery...

This page is ordered by a large number of div.

If you use FireBug(the plugin of FireFox) you can view the source.

You can use the Google Map's API. It's ordered the interface of Maps.

Look at the *Google API* you can got it.

Comment: I think a lot more interesting how the site can poll Twitter at this rate.